# Result of a Home Experiment with a capacitor

Tags: capacitance, voltage, home-experiment

With a voltmeter , I tested an 18V battery (9+9). It gave 18V. Then I took 2 aluminium square pieces and stuck them on 2 sides of wet flour. After 15 minutes the flour dried(no conduction). This way I made a capacitor. Then I tested the capacitor after connecting it's 2 plates (aluminium foils) to the voltmeter and it showed 0V.
Now the problem.
I charged the capacitor with the 18V battery for 3 minutes (later I charged it for 8 minutes but the results I will mention remained the same ).
After charging , I connected it to Voltmeter and it showed 1V
I allowed the capacitor to discharge for 5 minutes but the reading was stable at 1V even after 5 minutes. I took out the foils touched them for a 10 seconds or so and then reconnected to the Voltmeter and the needle was just deflected giving a reading below 0.5V (below least count). 
Questions
**Now isn't 3 minutes a lot to charge the capacitor to 18V (the battery was 18V and the wires were simply small ) ?
Why did it always charge to 1V only ? It should have been charged to 18 V within seconds. Then why it didn't ?
Secondly after 5 minutes of discharge it's voltage was still 1V. How can that be ? It should have been discharged within seconds. Even after touching the plates it was still not at 0. How can that be ? Why did it not charge to 18V and why did it not discharge ?**

Comment: It makes no sense, "sticking aluminum to wet floors". Also give a drawing. see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uC7HN9oFpZ0

Comment: Your homemade capacitor is faulty. Current runs through it when charging.

Comment: @Gert Ok , even if you say that the flour is wet and current runs through it and that's why it doesn't share to 18 V but then  what causes it not discharge

Comment: @annav  So according to you , if I make this capacitor with paper as dielectric , then it should be charged to 18V and discharge instantaneously.

Comment: http://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Electricity%20and%20magnetism/Electrostatics/text/Capacitor_charge_and_discharge_mathematics/index.html

Comment: @annav Yes , I understand that . What I was saying was if i connect good capacitor after charging to 18V , will the instantaneous reading of the Voltmeter be 18V or will there be no deflection because the capacitor discharges very vicky and that's why we use a ballistic galvanometer but it never tells the potential !

Comment: Aluminum has very poor surface conductivity since it oxidizes and especially it it's anodized. Might just be poor contacts for measuring and  applying the wires.

Comment: it depends on the time constants of the circuit you are using , including your measurement instrument.  Depending on the capacitance of the capacitor , that is why we have formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot measure the voltage of a typical capacitance with a typical voltmeter due to the voltage change of the source caused by the internal resistance of the voltmeter. Typical voltmeters (multimeters) have an input resistance of about $R_i=10 M \Omega$. Therefore, to measure a voltage $V$, a current $I=V_i/R_i$ has to flow during the measurement time of a couple of seconds without changing the voltage of the source. If you have an ideal capacitor with capacitance $C$ charged to a voltage $V$ and connect it to the voltmeter, the typical discharge time constant is $\tau=R_iC$. With a typical capacitance of such a set-up of several picofarad ($10^{-12}F$), the time constant is on the order of $\tau ∼10^{6}\Omega·10^{-12}F=10^{-6} s$, which is orders of magnitude shorter than the response time of the multimeter, and of you eye. So when you connect your multimeter to such a capacitor, the capacitor is discharged when the voltage meter gives a reading and the voltage reading is zero.

Therefore, in this experiment, you are measuring something not related to capacitance. In essence you have a galvanic cell (even when you think that the flour is "dry") and by "charging" it you induce chemical changes at the aluminum electrodes, so that after applying the battery for some time the electrodes are chemically different  and you have a galvanic cell with a measurable voltage.

Comment: The first sentence is, as written, misleading if not false.  An ideal capacitor has infinite *parallel* resistance but zero *series* resistance thus, there is no voltage division as implied.

Comment: Then what is that Voltmeter is measuring

Comment: @Shashank - You are measuring a galvanic voltage, as I explained in my answer. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_cell

Comment: @freecharly Ok , I understand bu Would a normal Voltmeter not be able to give the correct potential across a capacitor (good one , working factory made)?

Comment: @freecharly  I think you are right because I think that a Voltmeter can never measure the potential across a capacitor since it discharges so quickly . That's why we use a ballistic one

Comment: @Alfred Centauri - You are right, the first sentence is misleading. I will correct it in the answer. The result, however, is the same, i.e., that you cannot measure the voltage of a typical capacitance with a typical voltmeter due to the voltage change of the source due to the measurement.

Comment: @Shashaank - With a ballistic galvanometer you can measure the time integral over the discharge current, which is the charge of the capacitor. You cannot measure the voltage either.

Comment: @Shashank - In my extended introduction of the answer, you will find an explanation why you cannot measure the voltage on a typical capacitor with a typical voltmeter.

Comment: @freecharly  Yes I got it. I was thinking on the right track when I commented on Anna v's comment.

Comment: @freecharly  And is that 1V reading given surely due to galvanic potential , because it gave 1V for even paper instead of flour !

Comment: @Shashank - You are right,  this confirms the explanation.

Comment: I really "admire"  this coward who downvotes a perfectly correct answer without daring to explain why.

Comment: @freecharly The only thing I don't get is that how come  galvanic potential being developed due to the presence of a paper. In case of flour , the flour might be wet or since it is flour a potential could develop. But why in the case of paper ? Is gum (to stick paper) the suspect ??

Comment: @Shashaank - Did you use a glue when you attached the paper between the aluminum foils? Also, depending on air humidity there is always some moisture in the paper.

Comment: @freecharly  Yes , I did use glue between paper and aluminium exactly as shown in the video given in anna v's comment

Comment: @Shashank - I looked, it is made with glue stick. They contains electrolytes like sodium hydroxide. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glue_stick

You can further confirm the galvanic cell explanation by checking the voltage polarity after "charging", and also whether you can reverse the polarity after reverse charging. You can also look whether a very short "charging" already produces a lasting voltage. Let me know what you find out. You can also look whether you get galvanic corrosion in the foils after prolonged charging or shortening the charged plates and checking after a day.

Comment: @freecharly  Yes , I checked the polarity after charging and yes you are right. The polarity changed , the needle deflected the other way (a little  but that's enough to tell what's happening)on interchanging the connection to the voltmeter. Also reverse charging got reverse polarity. And the biggest , I got galvanic corrosion after shortening and the potential came to 0 after an hour or so (it kept falling gradually and that's I suppose the biggest proof in support of the galvanic explanation ). I'll try with other substances to see if different potentials are developed or not to furthercheck

Comment: @freecharly  It never came to me that galvanic potential could be an answer. Your answer and alfred centauri's tell correctly that Voltmeter would not be able to give the potential across any capacitor (good one too) and your explanation regarding the galvanic potential seems the best. Hence I vote it up!

Comment: @Shashaank- Your findings are a very nice demonstration of the galvanic origin of the observed effects. I wish you further success in your studies and lots of more fun as a physicist!

Answer (score 3):

I don't wish to address the experimental results given but instead, point out a potential flaw in the experiment.

Assuming that you've made a capacitor, i.e., that there isn't some conductive path between the plates, it is likely that the capacitance of your capacitor is *extremely* small.

For example, assume the area of your aluminum squares is $0.01 \mathrm{m}^2$ and the spacing is nominally $0.001\mathrm{m}$.  Then, assuming for simplicity $\epsilon_r = 1$, the capacitance is roughly

$$C = \frac{\epsilon_0 A}{d} = \frac{8.85\times10^{-12} \cdot 0.01}{0.001} \approx 100 \mathrm{pF}$$

If we assume that your voltmeter input resistance is, e.g., $10\mathrm{M\Omega}$, the measurement time constant is

$$\tau = R_{in}C =  10 \times 10^6 \cdot 100 \times 10^{-12} = 1 \mathrm{ms}$$

That is to say, assuming you have built a capacitor in fact and assuming it is charged to some voltage, when you connect your voltmeter across the charged capacitor, the capacitor will discharge through the input resistance in about

$$t_d = 5\cdot\tau = 5 \mathrm{ms}$$

If you want to be able to measure the voltage across the charged capacitor with a voltmeter, you'll need for the capacitance to be large enough such that the time constant is of the order of *seconds* which requires roughly $10,000$ times larger capacitance.

Comment: Buy then how come the Voltmeter is measuring 1V and the reading is stable

Comment: @Shashaank, I quote from my first sentence:  *"I don't wish to address the experimental results"*.